# How to sample randomly from a population?

Tags: random-generation, randomness

What do you think about the following method to perform a random sampling:

1. Generate as many floats (between 0 and 1) as individuals using a quantum random generator (each value appears only one time).
2. Assign floats to individuals.
3. Sort individuals according to the order of the floats.
4. Select individuals as needed.

Since the generator has good quality, is it risky to use this method?

Comment: It's a good procedure, except for the part about a "quantum random generator".  You don't need "quantum".  Moreover, I would recommend avoiding anything with the word "quantum" in its title unless you know the random generation field well, as there is a lot of quackery out there.  If you want a really good random number generator, ask for a cryptographic-strength pseudorandom number generator (e.g., `/dev/urandom` or `CryptGenRandom`).

Answer (score 6):

**It's a fine method in theory.**  To see why, we need to check two things.

1. Are all individuals selected with equal chances?  Yes, because the distributions of floats assigned to each individual are identical (they are uniform in $[0,1)$).
2. Are the selections independent?  Yes, because the floats assigned to the individuals are independent (presumably: that's part of what it means to be a "high quality" random number generator).

However, **this method tends to be inefficient** both in terms of computation time and memory resources.  It takes $O(n\log(n))$ time and $O(n)$ memory for selecting from a population of $n$.  Both can often be improved, sometimes greatly.

A general-purpose algorithm starts by considering how much of the population you need to sample.  If it's more than half the population, *then identify the individuals **not** in the sample* and select the rest (at a cost of $O(n)$ time).  This leaves us to identify no more than half the population, say $k$ out of $n$ individuals (with $2k \le n$).  Let their identifiers be in an array `population[0..n-1]`:

```
i = 0
selection = new set
while (i < k) {
    x = random float in [0,1)
    j = int(x * (n-i))
    adjoin population[j] to selection
    population[j] = population[n-1-i]
    i++
}
return selection
```

The key step--copying the last individual at `population[n-i-i]` into the space vacated by the recently selected individual, `population[j]`--doesn't actually require the entire `population[]` array to be in RAM: you can do it with a dictionary of $k$ pointers instead.  This makes the computation time $O(k \log(k))$ rather than $O(k)$ but reduces the storage requirements from $O(n)$ to $O(k)$, which can be substantial for small selections from huge populations stored offline.

The proof that this algorithm works is inductive.  Obviously it works for $n=1$.  For general $n\gt 1$, and assuming the `random float` procedure is a good one, then at the first step (a) each individual is chosen with equal probability and (b) that choice is independent of the next step, which selects $k-1$ individuals from a population of $n-1$.  Because this (inductively) is assumed to be correct, we are done.

Comment: Also, it seems as though we're dealing with an abstract `float` object, as opposed to say an IEEE floating-point standard one. Or, not?

Comment: @cardinal That's how I understand it.  Otherwise we would have to resolve ties, which the question specifically excludes in item (1).  If there's any worry, one could let the sorting routine decide ties uniformly at random (using the same high-quality RNG).

Comment: And, nonuniformity of representable numbers would also seem to come up, though it may be a minor point.

Comment: @cardinal That assumes the RNG is not "high quality."  Actually, come to think of it, the proposed sort-and-select procedure is immune to non-uniformity, whereas my suggested replacement is not.  All you need for the s&s algorithm is an RNG for *any* distribution that (a) is guaranteed independent from one call to the next and (b) has (for all practical purposes) zero chance of producing ties.

Comment: Yes, I agree with your last comment. My thoughts were focused on the uniformity claims of the OP but under a concrete (say, IEEE) floating-point object and (perhaps naively) separating the quality of the RNG from the end representation. Suppose $u \in [0,1]$ is your ideal "quantom random variate", but we must generate an IEEE float out of it. Then, we have a function $f : [0,1] \to \mathbb Q \cap [0,1]$ such that the image $\hat{u} = f(u)$ under $f$ is our final working object. But, we've lost uniformity, since $f$ is only uniform "conditional" (haha) on the exponent.